# React navigating to next page with scroll, if no element is being scrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a website with a nav bar that contains 5,6 buttons that when clicked navigates user to respective page. I'm using react router for that purpose. Some pages may have scroll bars and can be scrolled while some are not scrollable.

What I want to accomplish is, when there is a page that has scrollbar or if anything is being scrolled, then do nothing, just let the user scroll through the page, but if there is nothing being scrolled i.e (if user moves mouse wheel in not scrollable page or if the scroll end is reached and still moves the wheel) then navigate to the next page.

following is my base layout page which is common for all other pages. and what I tried to accomplish this behaviour.

```
function Layout({error}: Props) {
    const {pathname} = useLocation();
    const {data: user, isLoading} = useUser();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const parent = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const parentDiv = parent.current;
        let scrolling = false;
        parentDiv?.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
            console.log("scrolling >> scroll the element");
            scrolling = true;
        }, {capture: true, passive: false})
        parentDiv?.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
          if(scrolling) return scrolling = false;
            console.log("not scrolling >> go to next page");
        }, {passive: true});
    }, [])

    console.log("loading layout");
    const loadView = () => {
        if (error) return <ErrorPage />;
        if (pathname === "/dashboard") {
            if(isLoading) return <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" width="100%" height="100%" alignItems="center"><CircularProgress /></Box>
            if(user?.username) return <DashboardPage />
            return <ErrorPage />
        }
        return <Outlet />;
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <div ref={parent} id="wheeler" style={{width:"100vw", height: "100vh", overflowY: "auto"}}>
                <NavBar />
                <Stack direction="row" sx={{width: "100vw", height: PAGE_HEIGHT}}>
                <Box sx={{display: {sm: "flex", xs: "none"}}}>
                    <SocialMedia />
                </Box>
                {loadView()}
                </Stack>
            </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

What I tried is, I listened for both the events, i.e. 'scroll capture' and 'wheel' because scroll event does not trigger when nothing is scrolled so I had to listen for 'wheel' event in the parent div. and since 'scroll' event does not bubble so scroll capture was my option.

and use a variable if, the scroll has happened then set it to true and do not call the navigate function, but if the scroll event is not fired but wheel event is fired, then navigate the user.

but the problem is the wheel event seems to fire before the scroll event. and scroll event doesn't always fire. so there is no way to know if the scroll has really happened in the wheel event listener, as the scroll event fires only after this wheel event...

I tried using  time delay in the wheel event. i.e. setTimeout, and check if the scroll has happened, it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the wheel event fires before the scroll event. This means that if you check for the scroll event in the wheel event handler, it will always be false.

To solve this problem, you can use the throttle() function from the lodash library. The throttle() function takes a function and a delay as arguments, and it returns a new function that will only be called when the original function is called again after the delay has passed.

Here is the code that you can use:

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash';

const isScrolling = throttle(() => {
  // Check if the element is scrolling
}, 500);

const parentDiv = parent.current;
parentDiv?.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  // If the element is not scrolling, navigate to the next page
  if (!isScrolling()) {
    navigate('/next-page');
  }
});
```

The throttle() function will only call the isScrolling() function every 500 milliseconds. This means that if the user scrolls the element, the isScrolling() function will only be called once, after the 500 milliseconds have passed.

```
const myFunction = () => {
  // action after 500ms
  setTimeout(() => {
    // ...
  }, 500);
};
```

To wait for 500 ms, you can also use the setTimeout() function. there are ways to detect scrolling in React and JavaScript without using a third-party library. One way is to use the window.onscroll event listener. For example:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  // scroll action 
});
```

Comment: I have a confusion and a question, will the if(!isScrolling()){} function wait for 500ms as well or is it a promise and needs to be await...?
and the second is, isn't there something that can be done in react and javascript itself...? is it ideal to use a whole different library just to use a single function? if this is the only way than I'm gonna use it anyway...

Comment: @Chrishdev added more comments above

Comment: it isn't working, it behaves exactly same whether if I use setTimeout, throttle or no delay at all... or maybe my approach is wrong. Inside useEffect I'm using a variable to keep track of scroll. i.e. let scrolling = false; and inside scroll event listener update scrolling=true. and inside the throttle function if(scrolling) scrolling=false; else console.log("go to next page")

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I got it working, for anyone who wants to do it in the future, here is how I did it:

Basically the idea is to listen for when the mouse wheel scrolling ends. but since javascript does not have any event listener for that, we can create custom listener for that. like following code.

```js
const wheelStopListener = (
        element: HTMLDivElement,
        callback: (ev: WheelEvent) => void
    ) => {
        let handle: number | null = null;

        const onScroll = (e: WheelEvent) => {
            if (handle) {
                clearTimeout(handle);
            }
            handle = setTimeout(() => callback(e), 500);
        };
        element.addEventListener("wheel", onScroll);
        return () => element.removeEventListener("wheel", onScroll);
    };
```

and finally inside the react useEffect hook, we add two event listeners one is wheelStopListener and the other is "scrollend" listener.

and then, when the scrollend event is captured, and nothing has scrolled, then this means we can navigate to the next page. and if something has scrolled, it means user is scrolling through the content s in the the scrollable div so let him/her scroll and do not navigate.

```js
const pages = ["/", "/about", "/projects", "/contact"];
let hasScrolled = false;
let pageIndex = 0;

function Layout({ error }: Props) {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const parent = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const wheelStopListener = (
        element: HTMLDivElement,
        callback: (ev: WheelEvent) => void
    ) => {
        let handle: number | null = null;

        const onScroll = (e: WheelEvent) => {
            if (handle) {
                clearTimeout(handle);
            }
            handle = setTimeout(() => callback(e), 500);
        };
        element.addEventListener("wheel", onScroll);
        return () => element.removeEventListener("wheel", onScroll);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        pageIndex = pages.indexOf(pathname);

        const parentDiv = parent.current;
        if (!parentDiv) return;

        const onScrollEnd = () => hasScrolled = true;

        window.addEventListener("scrollend", onScrollEnd, { capture: true });

        const removeListener = wheelStopListener(parentDiv, (e: WheelEvent) => {
            if (hasScrolled) return (hasScrolled = false);
            if (!hasScrolled) {
                if (e.deltaY < 0) {
                    // scrolling down
                    if (pageIndex === 0) return;
                    console.log("move back");
                    --pageIndex;
                    navigate(pages[pageIndex]);
                } else if (e.deltaY > 0) {
                    // scrolling up
                    if (pageIndex === pages.length - 1) return;
                    ++pageIndex;
                    console.log("move front");
                    navigate(pages[pageIndex]);
                }
            }
        });

        return () => {
            removeListener();
            window.removeEventListener("scrollend", onScrollEnd);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
            <div
                ref={parent}
                id="wheeler"
                style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh", overflowY: "auto" }}
            >
                <NavBar />
                <Stack
                    direction="row"
                    sx={{ width: "100vw", height: PAGE_HEIGHT }}
                >
                    <Box sx={{ display: { sm: "flex", xs: "none" } }}>
                        <SocialMedia />
                    </Box>
                    {/** any contents */}
                </Stack>
            </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

the useEffect hook will monitor the scroll and mousewheel event in the parent div, ( we should capture the event as simply listening it will not work as the scroll event does not bubble ). And when when the events are triggered we can know when to navigate to the next page and then finally by observing the deltaY in the 'wheel' event we can identify which direction the wheel has be moved.

**Inside the useEffect hook Returning a function that removes event listener is very important otherwise it will malfunction with the react strict mode**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).